# Managing subdomain as part of website

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, subdomain

I want build a website with separating domain like this 
**www.schifoo.com** for main website 
**help.schifoo.com** for help menu 
**account.schifoo.com** for logged user 
**admin.schifoo.com** for admin 
**classroom.schifoo.com** some classroom online 
**blog.schifoo.com** for blog

my question is, do I need to copy each core of application into each subdomain folder? or I can share the module of my framework (laravel) for each subdomain, let's say admin user and student user share the same functionality, if there are changes of the featured then I have to change the both of program? or there is a way to mapping the route as if subdomain but inside the program is single application? I hope my question understandable.. thanks and before you vote me down please give me chance to refine my question (because my English so terrible).

Comment: in order: no,yes,maybe,yes

Comment: hmm do You have references that I could read, or simple example you could show me?

Comment: You should check out the docs @AnggaAriWijaya https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing), you can achieve this with sub-domain routing.

You just need to set up a group for each sub-domain of your application.

E.g `routes.php`:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'help.schifoo.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@helpHome');
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'account.schifoo.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@accountHome');
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'admin.schifoo.com'), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@adminHome');
});
```

This will allow you to keep all of your code inside one application, simplifying your code base and meaning you don't need to worry about session sharing between laravel applications etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @James, I have read laravel documentation many times, maybe I forgot if there is explanation like this because this is my first case using domain routing,, thanks for your positive feedback,,